# Get Column which contains a specific value

Tags: search, pyspark

Using pyspark. I would have a data frame like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [3,7] | 5 |
| hello | 4 | 666 |
| 4 | world | 4 |

Now I want to get the column name where the number 666 is included.

So the result should be "col3".

Thanks

**Edits**

Added other values than int. The great answers are focussed on only int values. Sry.

deleted: while we are at it, I guess the index can also be retrieved easily.

Comment: pyspark does not have indices. it is distributed as in parts of data are presents with each node, so it is impossible to index the data

Comment: Thanks. But by column should be possible

Comment: change the value within the filter and rest will be same. the solutions work with every data type. also, a column can have only 1 data type. please provide better examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check ASAP. Sry for the bad example. While not new to python, I am quite new to Spark

Answer (score 1):

here's an approach that creates an array using the columns and then filters it.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('allcols', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(c).alias('name'), func.col(c).cast('string').alias('value'))
                            for c in data_sdf.columns]
                          )
               ). \
    withColumn('cols_w_666_arr', 
               func.expr('transform(filter(allcols, x -> x.value = "666"), c -> c.name)')
               ). \
    drop('allcols'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+---+--------------+
# |c1 |c2 |c3 |cols_w_666_arr|
# +---+---+---+--------------+
# |1  |3  |5  |[]            |
# |2  |4  |666|[c3]          |
# |4  |666|4  |[c2]          |
# |666|666|4  |[c1, c2]      |
# +---+---+---+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(df.withColumn('result', F.array(*[F.array(F.lit(x).alias('y'), col(x).alias('y')) for x in df.columns]))#Create an array of cols and values
  .withColumn('result', expr("transform(filter(result, (c,i)->(c[1]==666)),(c,i)->c[0])"))#Filter array with 666 and extract col
 .show(truncate=False))

|col1|col2|col3|result|
+----+----+----+------+
|1   |3   |5   |[]    |
|2   |4   |666 |[col3]|
|4   |6   |4   |[]    |
```